# Neural Network Backpropogation code not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I need to write a simple neural network that consists of 1 output node, one hidden layer of 3 nodes, and 1 input layer (variable size). For now I am just trying to train on the xor data so lets presume that there are 3 input nodes (one node represents the bias and is always 1). The data is labeled 0,1.

I did out the equations for backpropogation and found that despite being so simple, my code does not converge to the xor data being correct.

Let W be the 3x3 matrix of weights connecting the input and hidden layer, and w be the 1x3 matrix that connects the hidden to output layer. Here are some helper functions for my method

```
def feed_forward_predict(x, W, w):
    sigmoid = lambda x: 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    z = np.array(list(map(sigmoid, np.matmul(W, x))))
    L = sigmoid(np.matmul(w, z))
    return [L, z, x]
```

this just takes in a value and makes a prediction using the formula sig(w*sig(W*x)). We also have

```
def calculate_objective(data, labels, W, w):
    obj = 0
    for point, label in zip(data, labels):
        L, z, x = feed_forward_predict(point, W, w)
        obj += (label - L)**2
    
    return obj
```

which calculates the Mean Squared Error for a bunch of given data points. Both of these functions should work as I checked them by hand. Now the problem comes in for the back propogation algorithm

```
def back_prop(traindata, trainlabels):

    sigmoid = lambda x: 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    sigmoid_prime = lambda x: np.exp(-x)/((1+np.exp(-x))**2)

    W = np.random.rand(3, len(traindata[0]))
    w = np.random.rand(1, 3)

    obj = calculate_objective(traindata, trainlabels, W, w)
    print(obj)


    epochs = 10_000
    eta = .01
    prevobj = np.inf
    i=0
    while(i < epochs):

        prevobj = obj

        dellw = np.zeros((1,3))
        for point, label in zip(traindata, trainlabels):
            y, z, x = feed_forward_predict(point, W, w)
            dellw += 2*(y - label) * sigmoid_prime(np.dot(w, z)) * z

        w -= eta * dellw

     
        for point, label in zip(traindata, trainlabels):
            y, z, x = feed_forward_predict(point, W, w)
            temp = 2 * (y - label) * sigmoid_prime(np.dot(w, z))
            # Note that s,u,v represent the hidden node weights. My professor required it this way
            dells = temp * w[0][0] * sigmoid_prime(np.matmul(W[0,:], x)) * x
           
            dellu = temp * w[0][1] * sigmoid_prime(np.matmul(W[1,:], x)) * x
            
            dellv = temp * w[0][2] * sigmoid_prime(np.matmul(W[2,:], x)) * x


        dellW = np.array([dells, dellu, dellv])
        W -= eta*dellW

        obj = calculate_objective(traindata, trainlabels, W, w)

        i = i + 1
        print("i=", i, " Objective=",obj)

    return [W, w]
```

However this code, despite seemingly being correct in terms of the matrix multiplications and derivatives I took, does not converge to anything. In fact the error consistantly bounces: it will fall, then rise, then fall back to the same spot, then rise again. I believe that the problem lies with the W matrix gradient but I do not know what exactly it is.

If you'd like to see for yourself what is happening, the input data I used is

```
0: 0 0 1
0: 1 1 1
1: 1 0 1
1: 0 1 1
```

where the first number represents the label. I also set the random seed to `np.random.seed(0)` just so that I could be consistant with my matrices I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, in my code I was not summing the hidden node weight derivatives and instead was assigning at every loop iteration. The correct version would be as follow

```
for point, label in zip(traindata, trainlabels):
      y, z, x = feed_forward_predict(point, W, w)
      temp = 2 * (y - label) * sigmoid_prime(np.dot(w, z))
      # Note that s,u,v represent the hidden node weights. My professor required it this way
      dells += temp * w[0][0] * sigmoid_prime(np.matmul(W[0,:], x)) * x
           
      dellu += temp * w[0][1] * sigmoid_prime(np.matmul(W[1,:], x)) * x
            
      dellv += temp * w[0][2] * sigmoid_prime(np.matmul(W[2,:], x)) * x
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are attempting to setup a manual version of stochastic gradient decent with a fixed learning rate (a classic NN problem).

Some notes on your code. It is very difficult to follow all the steps you are doing with so much loops and inconsistencies. In general, it defeats the purpose of using np.array() if you are using loops. Likewise you should know that np.matmul() is * and np.dot() is @. It is unclear how you are using the derivative. You have it explicitly stated at the start for the activation function and then partially derived in the middle of your loop for the MSE. Ugh.

Some other pointers. Explicitly state all your functions and your data, those should be globals. Those should also be derived all at once based on your fixed data as np.array(). In particular, note that while traditional statistics (like finding the line of best fit) means that we are solving for a fixed set of weights given a random variable; in stochastic gradient decent, we are doing the opposite. We are instead fixing the random variable to our data and optimizing our weights. Hence, your functions should only have your weights as "free variables", everything else is fixed. It is important to follow what is being fixed and what is free to update. Your code does not reflect that you know what is being update and what is fixed.

SGD algorithm outline:

1. Random params.
2. Update params by moving params a small percentage in the direction of lowest decent.
3. Run step (2) for a specified amount of time.
4. Print your params.

Example of SGD code (here is an example of performing SGD to find the line of best fit for some data).

```
import numpy as np

#Data
X = np.random.random((100,))                   #Random points
Y = (2.3*X + 8) + 0.1*np.random.random((100,)) #Linear model + Noise

#Functions (only free variable is the params) (we want the F of best fit under MSE)
F      = lambda p : p[0]*X+p[1] 
dF     = lambda p : np.array([X,np.ones(X.shape)])
MSE    = lambda p : (1/Y.shape[0])*((Y-F(p))**2).sum(0)
dMSE   = lambda p : (1/Y.shape[0])*(-2*(Y-F(p))*dF(p)).sum(1)

#SGD loop
lr     = 0.05
epochs = 1000
params = np.array([0.0,0.0])
for i in range(epochs):
    params -= lr*dMSE(params)

print(params)
```

Hopefully, written this way it is super clear exactly where the subtraction of the gradient is occurring and exactly how it is calculated. Note also, in case it wasn't clear, the derivative in both dF and dMSE is with respect to the params. Obviously this is a toy problem that can be solved explicitly with the scipy module. Hence, SGD is a clearly useless way to optimize two variables.

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
params = linregress(X,Y)
print(params)
```

Comment: I understand what GD, SGD is attempting to optimize, its just that when it came to the specifics of implementing the derivative of the weight parameters my math seems to be off. If only stack overflow had mathjax then maybe I could frame my question better. Also the loops were done since the gradient of all points is also just the sum of the gradients. I'm not super experiences with numpy so I didn't wanna push it

Comment: No worries. I don't want to do your specific problem for you (per your request), so hopefully the toy example above might help shed light on how to organize your functions and what they should look like. Ya, stackoverflow is not good for math type questions. Feel free to post on math.stackexchange instead or mathoverflow if you feel your question is more research like. You can link the question here if you want me to take a look.

Comment: Yeah I might link it there. Tragically my code is limited to this format by professor specifications; I took out all the comments per line saying "do this here" for the sake of brevity, but this isn't my first choice of format haha